# Difficulty with java program passing the txt file into an array list to setup the rest of my program

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In the student sample for this book you will find a text file named `1994 weekly gas averages.txt`. The file contains 52 lines of text that represent average weekly gas. Line one contains average price for week one and line 2 contains the average price for week 2 etc.
Write a program that reads the gas prices from the file into an array of an `ArrayList`. The program should do the following.

1. Display the lowest average price of the year, along with the week number for that price, and the 
   name of the month which it occurred.
2. Display the highest average price of the year, along with the week number for that price, and the 
   name of the month which it occurred.
3. Display the average gas price for each month.

Txt file gas averages. I'm just starting out with java. Whatever answer is provided, could you keep it simple enough for me to understand since I’m having difficulty.

[Part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O39JS.png)

0.992
0.995
1.001
0.999
1.005
1.007
1.016
1.009
1.004
1.007
1.005
1.007
1.012
1.011
1.028
1.033
1.037
1.04
1.045
1.046
1.05
0.856
1.065
1.073
1.079
1.095
1.097
1.103
1.109
1.114
1.13
1.157
1.161
1.165
1.161
1.156
1.15
1.14
1.129
1.12
1.114
1.106
1.107
1.171
1.123
1.122
1.113
1.117
1.127
1.131
1.134
1.125

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Do not upload images of code but the actual code as text into a code block

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code for reading from file and calculating the lowest price:

```
public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
      List<String> averages = getAllLinesFromFileFromPath("/averages.txt");

      double lowest = Double.valueOf(averages.get(0));
      for (String line: averages)  {
        Double weekValue = Double.valueOf(line);
        if (lowest>weelValue)  {lowest = weekValue;}
      }
    }

    public static List<String> getAllLinesFromFileFromPath(String filename)  {
        try  {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Paths.get(filename).toFile()));
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine())!=null)  {
                result.add(line);
            }
            br.close();

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```